# How do I set custom resize handles with jQuery UI?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm using jQuery UI to allow my page elements to be resizable, but I'd like to set custom handles.  I've tried what I think should work, but it doesn't.

The basic html is:

```
 <div id="element_x" class="resizable">
  <div id="overlay_x" class="element_buttons">
   <div id="resize_element_x" class="resize_element ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"><img src="images/site/handle_resize.png" border=0 title="Resize this element" /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I set it up like this:

```
   var reposition = '';
   $(function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
     containment: "#viewPage",
     handles: {"e,s,se" : { e: '.ui-resizable-e', s: '.ui-resizable-s', se: '.ui-resizable-se'}},
     resize: function(event, ui){
       reposition = ui.position;
     }
    });
   });
```

This produces the correct handle in the right place, but when I try to resize, it just doesn't do anything! What might be wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your custom handle syntax is wrong. This works for me:

```
   var reposition = '';
   $(function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
     containment: "#viewPage",
     handles: { 'e': '.ui-resizable-e', 's': '.ui-resizable-s', 'se': '.ui-resizable-se'},
     resize: function(event, ui){
       reposition = ui.position;
     }
    });
   });
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @GauravSharma Thanks, I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

[The solution is not mine, but it shows exactly what the problem and the solution is:](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/pFfKz/)

```
<p><a href="http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4310">jQuery UI #4310</a> - Custom resizable handles do not work unless the ui-resizable-xy and ui-resizable-handle classes are added.</p>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="border bottom_right ui-resizable-se ui-resizable-handle"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.container').resizable({
           handles: { se: '.bottom_right' } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

For me it works! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/pFfKz/

Answer (score 0):

for me the quickest solution is to change the resizer style.
Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myResizableContainerID").resizable({
  handles: "se"
});

$(".ui-resizable-se").css({
  width: "100%",
  height: "20px",
  background: "blue",
});
```

});